# Andoird Стандартные кнопки в уведомлении

Tags: android

Создал уведомление с кнопками, на кнопки не появляются, они скрыты, чтобы стало из видно нужно потянуть уведомление вниз, но мне надо, чтобы сразу их было видно. Что надо добавить в код, чтобы кнопки появились?
Уведомление создается из сервиса. 
И сразу еще вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы нажимаю на эти кнопки status bar не закрывался, но при этом сервис как-то реагировал на нажатие кнопки.
Вот код:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("Пришла посылка!")
        .setContentTitle("Посылка")
        .setContentText(
                "Это я, почтальон Печкин. Принес для вас посылку")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Открыть", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Отказаться", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Другой вариант", pIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .build();


notificationManager.notify(0, builder);
```

Comment: Про второй вопрос - ничего не понятно, можете более детально объяснить или скрин приложить?

Comment: Про второй вопрос: я хочу, чтобы было примерно как в приложении "Радио России" при запуске радио в статус панеле появлялось уведомление с кнопками и при нажатии на первую музыка останавливалась и статус бар не закрывался.

Comment: а какая версия андройда используется?

Comment: Тестировал на Android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что у вас переизбыток кнопок, попробуйте убрать одну кнопку(а лучше два!), а так код - вполне рабочий. Попробуйте так:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("Title");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
this,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Теперь уведомление показывается до тех пор, пока вы его не отмените с помощью:

```
mNotifyMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Обновлено. Посмотрите еще разок [документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), может что-то упустили.

Comment: Ставил разное количество кнопок, все равно они скрываются.